# Trouble using htaccess in core php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is **Htaccess** code to show the desired URL

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

But it is not working.

I want my url to be: **www.site.com/title**

I want to show the title in url and want to get the id.

Comment: Complete your requirements. `www.site.com/title` doesn't even have id in it. How will your `/page.php` be called?

Comment: actually i need this type of URL. Previously i have the URL is like www.site.com/id. But i want url like site.com/title

Comment: Now I have this type of url:
http://www.pathikthetraveller.com/page.php?id=2
but I want to use something like:
http://www.pathikthetraveller.com/about-us

In Database I have 2 field first for id[2] & second for title[About Us]

and URL is:
<a href="<?php echo BASEURL.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$menu['title']));?>"><?php echo $pagemenu['title'];?></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```